# How to save Spring form data using jquery ajax without refreshing page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

i try out [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm) example... where student class object is getting at controller side. and we can use it directly. but here the page is getting submitted.

here i want it call the post method using jquery ajax and post data as class object. instead of sending each input field value.

how can i achieve this?

for example i want to send post request to this controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
   ModelMap model) {
      //here will be my code to use student object....

      return "result";
   }
```

using this Spring form..

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer with an existing question.. [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

For Spring's model attribute mapping to work, you only have to make sure the form input names stay consistent. The best way to progressively convert your traditional form submit to an ajax style form submit is to trap the form submit event, serialize the form and make an ajax call. Since all param names and values are going to remain consistent, your backend code will work as is.

Note: You will have to handle responses differently though, since a normal form submit returns the success or error page, while with ajax you'll need something else. But since this question is about form submission, won't go into details about response handling.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I would take a look at the jquery form plugin. This handles ajax forms pretty nicely. We are currently using it for each form in our spring mvc app.

Comment: the form plugin is one of the options mentioned in the referenced Q&A, I personally prefer to stay away from plugins, unless I really need them.. if a simple serialize is all I need I would rather do it myself.

Comment: thanks @Akshay ..this is what i m looking for ..the link you have given its work for me....

Comment: hi.. @Akshay and  at martin , now i am getting spring form at controller, now i have to populate entity object from the controller on spring form using jquery. kindly guide me..

Comment: @Bhushan, if you can post a question with some more details about what you are facing, I'd be happy to take a look (and so will lots of other SO users). It's difficult to understand what problem you are facing in comments :)

Comment: @Akshay ,sir i have posted Question here is link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334527/how-to-populate-entity-object-values-on-spring-form-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert form values to json, and use and an ajax post request to submit data to server.

I did it using the toObject plugin for jQuery. And the JSON stringify function.

Comment: thanks for your reply ...i can convert form values to json. like {"name":"name value",...} something like this... but instead of assign each value i want post class object as in the above example student object gets in controller... Or is there there is any way to convert modelattribute object get converted to json.

Comment: You can convert it to any json structure you like.  And then create a controller method to accept it. So yes it will look something like {"myclass":{"name":"john"}}.My formatting/syntax isprobably borked, I always froget the corect json. But you defintiely can, thats kida th epoitn of json.

Comment: @Bhushan the other answer is good aswell if you want to use the same controller method/pre existing method with working paramter mappings.

Comment: hi @NimChimpsky .. now i am getting spring form at controller as entity object, now i have to populate entity object from the controller on spring form using jquery. kindly guide me..