# How to populate entity object values on Spring Form using jquery/ajax?

Tags: ajax, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I have the Spring form

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/HelloWeb/addStudent" id="myForm">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

i can submit this form to controller using

```
$.post('{controller path}', $('#myForm').serialize());
```

now i want to populate entity object using jquery/Ajax on the this form and object will be returned from controller.

kindly guide me?

here is controller that call new page and populate object data on form...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, ModelMap model)
{ 
Student stud =new Student(); 
//here will be my code to use student object.... 
return new ModelAndView("ViewStudent", "SpringWeb",stud); 
}
```

but this method load new page ...instead of calling new i want do this logic on same page

Comment: I am sorry but I still dont understand.. what do you mean by "now i want to populate entity object using jquery/Ajax on the this form and object will be returned from controller."? When this form is submitted using ajax, is your controller not receiving values? or when the form loads, the data set into the form object in the controller not seen on the form? Adding controller methods for showing the form, and handling the submit to the question will also help.

Comment: last one is working properly ... now this is different thing i am trying to show data on form like this controller does.. @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
   ModelMap model) {  Student stud =new Student();
      //here will be my code to use student object....
     
      return new ModelAndView("ViewStudent", "SpringWeb",stud);
   }

Comment: @AkshaySinghal , i have edited question. better to understand my question. just one thing i want to do is populate data/object that is getting in response data of post method on the form.

Answer (score 1):

The `form: tags` are interpreted on the server side, and generate regular HTML tags on the client side. Since jQuery is only running on the client side, it won't be able to find things using the form: tags. Try running the page and viewing the HTML source, then base your jQuery selectors on what you see there.