# How to show data on same page after controller call?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

The scenario is like i am having a search button on page and when i like on search button then result data should be come on same page. i am using Spring MVC and jsp.

My Welcome page is:-

In this i am searching some data by entering data in textbox.When the page is loaded then filedset having "search results" id must not be displayed and after pressing on search button data must come is required format on same page.

```
<form:form name="frmPrfAdmin" modelAttribute="profileAdmin" action="searchResult.html" method="post" >

          <%-- <form class="" role="form"> --%>
                <fieldset class="" id="SearchCriteria">
                    <div class="boxed-body">
                        <div class="boxed-body-padded">
                            <h3>Search Criteria</h3>
                            <p>This screen allows you to search user profiles</p>
                            <div class="span8">
                                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li class="active" ><a href="#username" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="username" aria-expanded="true">Username</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a  href="#consituent" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="consituent" aria-expanded="true">Constituent ID</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#name" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="name" aria-expanded="true">Name</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a  href="#email" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="email" aria-expanded="true">User Email</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active boxed-group" id="username" onclick="fnTabClick('username');">
                                        <div class="tab-pad">
                                            <div class="input-group span8">
                                               <form:input type="text" path="userName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Username"   id="idUserName" />

                                                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="return profAdmSrchSubmit();" />
                                                </span>
                                            </div> <p>
                                                User Name is selected when a user creates an Demo ID.     </p>   </div></div>   </div></div>

                                    <fieldset class="boxed-group" id="search-results">  
                    <div class="boxed-head">
                        <h3>Search Results</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxed-body">
                        <div class="table-wrapper">

                            <table class="table table-striped search-results">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="username">User Name</th>
                                        <th class="constituentid">Constituent ID</th>
                                        <th class="lastname">Last Name</th>                                 
                                        <th class="firstname">First Name</th>
                                        <th class="email">Email Address</th>
                                        <th class="member">Member</th>
                                        <th class="acsnetwork">ACS Network</th>
                                        <th class="eright-username">Valid eRights User Name</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>


                                  <tr>
                                <tbody>

                                         <tr>                  
                                       <td class="username">  Anurag </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>

                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
```

Comment: I guess, you will have to make ajax call and then render the response in your page.

Comment: Any link or reference will help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link. It tell about `How to save Spring form data using jquery ajax without refreshing page`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16280861/3898076

or you can refer [**this**](http://www.raistudies.com/spring/spring-mvc/ajax-spring-mvc-3-annonations-jquery/) example.

**Update:**

For your problem statement. You can submit your form to the controller which will prepare the search result. Then render new jsp page(same jsp). And in your jsp you can check if that binded bean is present then render your result part else don't render it.

Comment: Thanks for link but this is not solving my problem

Comment: What issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

I have solution of above problem.

I set a model attribute in my .java class and called the attribute in jsp file in  tag

In java class

```
mv.add("show",true);
```

In jsp

```
<c:if test="${show}==true"> If true then perform operation   </c:if>
```

Comment: <c:if test="${show==true}">. The code between {} is the expression language.